# Is there an easy way to publish multiple ClickOnce installations of the same application?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I was wondering if there is an easy way to use ClickOnce deployment to publish multiple versions of the same application.  For instance, I have an application that we distribute to several of our sister companies for use, and so I need to have that companies name set in the config file so that it displays their name on the splash screen and the reports the program outputs (and possibly change the application name as well).

My only thought on how to do this is to have separate directories on the web server and place a published deployment on each one.  In visual studio I will have to set the correct name in the config file, publish the files to the server, go back and change the name in the config file, publish again, etc until each company has their own individual deployment.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an MSBuild script that will update the config file, update the location of where to publish the ClickOnce files and then start the actual ClickOnce publishing process.  Have the script loop through your different companies until they are all complete.